# XSLT is not apply to xml

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I'm trying to implement  XSLT to XML use  Xpath expression to view stop name that have "Adelaide" street when I view the xml into browser in Web browser is not apply the XSLT it view all xml data without emplemant XSLT

```
XML

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="ltcstops.xslt"?>
<allstops>
  <stop number="2504" name="Main &amp; Bainard EB">
    <location>
      <latitude>42.91033567</latitude>
      <longitude>-81.29671483</longitude>
    </location>
    <routes>28</routes>
  </stop>
  <stop number="20" name="Adelaide &amp; Ada NB">
    <location>
      <latitude>42.9742886</latitude>
      <longitude>-81.2252341</longitude>
    </location>
    <routes>16</routes>
  </stop>
  <stop number="22" name="Adelaide &amp; Central Ave NB">
    <location>
      <latitude>42.9945666</latitude>
      <longitude>-81.2343441</longitude>
    </location>
    <routes>16</routes>
  </stop>
<allstops>

XSLT

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
      <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>
      <xsl:variable name="theStreet" select="'Adelaide'" />
      <xsl:variable name="theTitle" select="concat('stop ', $theStreet)" />
      <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:element name="html">
          <xsl:element name="body">
            <table style="width:720px" border="3">
              <tr>
                <td>Stop #</td>
                <td>Route #</td>
                <td>Name</td>
              </tr>
              <xsl:apply-templates select="/stop/@name=$theStreet"/>
            </table>
          </xsl:element>
        </xsl:element>
      </xsl:template>
      <xsl:template match="stop">
        <tr>
          <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="@number"/>
          </td>
          <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="routes"/>
          </td>
          <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following XPath, instead:

```
allstops/stop[contains(@name,$theStreet)]
```

And your input XML doesn't have proper closing tag for `<allstops>`